# If cell A1 contains 'john' then cell B1 should equal 'red', if cell A2 contains 'paul' then cell V2 should equal 'blue'

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Let's say we have a table like below which pairs each name with a colour:

| Name | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| Paul | blue |
| John | red |

I would like a formula in the 2nd column below that will say: if cell contains 'Paul' then colour is 'blue' etc.

| Data | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| 52!Paul*22342 | ? |
| John/23rff | ? |

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the lookup table of names and colors is in `Names!A2:B`, and that the text strings in the `Data` column always start with an name consisting of purely alphabetic characters A-Z, with optional leading or trailing non-alphabetic characters, you can use `regexextract()` and `vlookup()`, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  names, namesAndColors, 
  map( 
    arrayformula( regexextract(names, "[A-z]+") ), 
    lambda( 
      name, 
      iferror( vlookup(name, namesAndColors, columns(namesAndColors), false) ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)(A2:A, Names!A2:B)
```

Comment: Apologies but I have just changed my question slightly because the data does not always start with a name.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please show _realistic-looking_ sample data rather than gibberish.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your answer works for me as long as the name is at the beginning of the string. Is there a way to make it work if the name is contained anywhere in the string?

In response to your comment: my question is representative of the data I'm working with, which is like gibberish

Comment: The formula I gave you works with the sample data you show.

Comment: If your real data is considerably different from what you show in the question, you may need a completely different solution. If that is the case, please post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with more realistic-looking sample data.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again!

Comment: Some of my data points have the following format: "bring john tot" or "tulipjohn". To confirm, I would like the formula return John's colour for these data points, but the formula in the answer does not do that currently. Should I post a new question for this?

Comment: Please do. In the new question, show say 15 rows of representative and realistic-looking sample data in the source data table, and say 10 text strings you want to look up in that table. Try to identify the most problematic cases and include them in the sample. Also show your manually entered desired results.